# An English word for 'Jaltarang' - music played by striking water-filled containers with a baton

Tags: word-request

In India, it's called 'Jaltarang' where 'jal' means water and 'tarang' is melody. I wonder whether or not there's a word for the same in English. A near-to-it word will be okay, if not precisely defining the instrument.

Here is the picture. Note that the vessel could be anything...right from glass bowls to crystal glasses.

[image: Jaltarang - an illustration of person seated on the floor in a semi-circle of bowls filled with liquid with a baton in each hand]

Most important: this would be different than *glass harp* where fingers are used. Here, a baton or small metal stick is used.

Comment: Water xylophone? https://onelittleproject.com/how-to-make-a-water-xylophone/

Comment: This is not just an Indian thing, but also a fun science experiment for children. [This page](https://www.connectionsacademy.com/resources/instructographics/music-water-glasses) suggests musical (water) glasses but I'm not sure how widespread the use of this word is.

Comment: @JavaLatte almost that... thanks for the word.

Answer (score 2):

There's no exact English word.  As with the sitar or tabla, names of musical instruments (and other cultural elements) normally don't translate well, and so are left untranslated.  So use *jaltarang* or perhaps *jal tarang*.  If necessary explain what it is perhaps in a parathetical aside.

> The class watched a demonstration of the *jal tarang* (an Indian musical instrument consisting of ceramic bowls partially filled with water). The performer played several traditional and modern pieces on the *jal tarang*, which all the students enjoyed.